# What's the best way to load the google maps api into angular2?

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

I have played around with [angular2 maps](https://angular-maps.com/docs/api/latest/ts/), but in the end I think I want to use the [google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) api directly.

What's the best/right way to load this into angular 2? Currently I am loading it via a script tag, inserted into the index.html file, like so.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ourlatitude</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
</head>
<body>
    <script 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_api_key">
    </script>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I create a map in a component inside the ngAfterViewInit() hook of the component that will hold the map.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mymap.nativeElement, {zoom: 4, center: {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044} });
}
```

This seems to work, but adding the script tag does not seem like the right thing to do.  I tried adding the script to the angular-cli.json scripts: [] array, but that does not seem to work (the call to `new google.maps.Map()` fails with google being undefined).

BTW, I installed the types via `npm install --save @types/google-maps` and they seem to be recognized.

Comment: This is one way to do it or you may want to use a wrapper written for Angular specifically.  Also when using vanilla lib, you should create the map outside of NgZone to prevent every event from the map from triggering a change detection in the Angular app.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I integrated google-maps:

1. I created script load service, which loads scripts only when
   required -

   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

   ```
   @Injectable()
   export class ScriptLoadService {

     constructor() { }

     public loadScript(url, id, c): void {
       if (!document.getElementById(id)) {
         const script = document.createElement('script');
         script.type = 'text/javascript';
         script.src = url;
         script.id = id;
         if (c) {
           script.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
             c(null, e);
           }, false);
         }
         document.head.appendChild(script);
       }
     }

   }
   ```
2. Add your googleMapURL in your environment file

> googleMapURL:
> 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&libraries=places'

3. Now you can use use google maps api in any component by injecting
   ScriptLoadService and in ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit call loadScript
   funcion:

   @ViewChild('mapElement') mapElm: ElementRef; // to display map

   ```
   constructor( private scriptLoadService: ScriptLoadService ) {} // inject the service

     ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.scriptLoadService.loadScript(environment.googleMapURL, 'google-map', () => {
         this.center = new google.maps.LatLng(
           this.lat,
           this.lng);

         // Create map
         this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElm.nativeElement, {
           zoom: 18,
           center: this.center,
           disableDefaultUI: true,
           scrollwheel: false,
         });

         // Add Marker to current location detected by browser
         this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: this.center,
           map: this.map
         });
   });
   }
   ```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Getting started](https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html), this document let's you start from scratch and build an Angular 2 app with angular2-google-maps. It is more cleaner and more efficient way to load google maps api, as it is integrated using angular2.

To familiarize yourself with angular2 and angular2-google-maps and don't want to set up a full project with NPM, you can use the following Plunker. It has all the dependencies to play with Angular2, Typescript and of course angular2-google-maps: [Plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/YX7W20?p=preview).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.21/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/typescript@1.8.10/lib/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
    System.import('app')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>

  </body>

</html>


<!-- 
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->
```

Comment: I actually know how to use angular2-google-maps.  It's what I am currently using, but I was interested in just loading the raw api directly,  and specifically,  asynchronously,  and without adding a script tag to my index.  There are a few approaches, such as appending the script in code inside the component, but most seem a bit hacky,  so I am asking what would really be the correct way to load this api that is angular 2 friendly.